# Does a SIPS server need a RADIUS server?

Tags: sip, radius, sip-server, freeradius, opensips

This may be a naive question, but I'll ask it anyway. According to http://www.kamailio.org/docs/openser-radius-1.0.x.html, a SIP server should be paired with a RADIUS server for authentication. How about SIPS? Does a SIPS server have a built-in equivalent of a RADIUS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement for a SIP server to support a RADIUS server.  It's a function of the SIP server implementation.

I assume by "SIPS", you mean secure SIP connections to the SIP Server.  SIPS is part of the main [SIP RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt).  Again, a SIP server may/may not support SIPS.  Most likely tho, it will support SIPS.

So really what your question should be:  Is there a sip server that supports SIPS and RADIUS servers.

Since the Kamailio OpenSER has [documentation on TLS support](http://kamailio.org/docs/tls-1.3.x.html) then yes it support SIPS.